# Getting the Index of the Minimum Value in Selected Rows of Dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am using the following to return the minimum value in selected rows of a dataframe. It does the job but I cannot work out how to also get the index.

How do I do this?

```
local_low = df.loc[i:next_high_index, 'CostX'].min()
```

Comment: Use `idxmin` to get the index of the min, then you can use that to index again and get the min. Or if performance is not critical compute both `idxmin` and `min`.